# Problems importing ROS messages (ROS Noetic)

Tags: ros, python, rosmessage, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a code in Python to create a node to subscribe to a topic, however, I am having a little problem with the libraries, when I write the messages that I need to import, it appears in VSCode that I do not have access to them. On the screen it tells me that I cannot access the String of std_msgs.msg nor Joy of sensor_msgs.msg. Does anyone know how I can fix that error?

ROS Answers still won't let me upload photos because I'm new but what I wrote at the top of my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

import rospy

#It won't let me import these two messages:
from std_msgs.msg import String 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy

from control_msgs.msg import FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal
import math
```

If I click on String or Joy I get a message that says: "String" is not accessed Pylance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400097/problems-importing-ros-messages-(ros-noetic)/) by [LuisEFA1998](https://answers.ros.org/users/99578/luisefa1998/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general this is not an issue. Because your vscode workspace does not know from where the std_msgs or any ros includes are coming from. But still you will be able to run your code without any error.

To get rid of the warning underline, you can add following thing to your `.vscode/settings.json`

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [ "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/ ], "
```

For an example of a good vscode configuration you can visit [here](https://github.com/athackst/vscode_ros2_workspace/tree/foxy/.vscode). The only thing is it is for ros2.

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2022-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-05**:
Your repo might be set to private. I'm getting a 404

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-05**:
@Joe28965 I have updated the link to the original repo from where I forked it. Thanks for informing.